# How can I prove these statements?

Tags: general-topology

I would be very glad if you helped me solving this problem. It's about topology.
Okay let's begin :

Let $A$ be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb R$. Let $x_0 \in A$ and $B = [x_0,\infty) ∩ A^c$ (complement of $A$)

First I should prove that $B$ is a non-empty, closed set. Then I should prove that :

1. $B$ is bounded below.
2. $\inf B > x_0$
3. $\inf B$ doesn't belong to $A$.
4. $[x_0, \inf B) \subseteq A$.

Then I should explain how to deﬁne a number $\beta$ so that $(\beta,\inf B) \subseteq  A$, where $\beta$ doesn't belong to $A$.

I really can't get up with proofs for these question. Can you please help me solving this or at least give me some hint or sketch? I would be very grateful. Thank you :)

Comment: I just solved one of these statements, it's obvious that x0 doesn't belong to B since x0 belong to A. And when we prove that B is bounded below and inf(B) exist we can say that inf(B)> x0 because all elements in B are greater than x0. Is that correct?

Comment: $B$ can be the empty set in case you choose $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MetinY. Yes I agree but here A is a subset of R.

Comment: If you meant to say proper subset, then it is ok!

Comment: Yeah but how can I prove that B is not empty in this case?

Comment: I suspect $B$ can be empty in either way. Suppose $x_o \in (x', \infty)=A$ where $x'<x_0$. Obviously, $A$ is open. Then we have, $B=[x_o, \infty)\cap (- \infty, x']=\emptyset$.

Comment: You definitely nee dthat the complement of $A$ is not bounded from above to show that $B$ is nonempty. Everything else follows readily without this additional assumption (using the correct interpretations of $\inf\emptyset=+\infty$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry but I didn't understand your point, how can B be a non empty set ? Metin just gave us a counter example which contradict the question of the book how can this be possible ? thank you

Comment: @user93765 $B$ can be empty or non-empty with the conditions as stated now. According to the problem statement you have to show that $B$ is non-empty, which is impossible *because* $B$ can be empty or non-empty. In order to be able to *show* that $B$ is non-empty, one needs additional, stronger conditions. I gave an example of such a stronger condition (if $A^c$ is bounded one might "accidentally" pick $x_0$ such that $B=\emptyset$, if $A^c$ is unbounded one can't). All other sub-tasks of the problem statement are doable without stronger conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is the interdection of two closed sets $[x_0,\infty)$ and $A^c$ (they are closed because their complements are open).
As noted in the comments, $B$ might be empty.
Indeed, if $A^c$ is bounded from above (by $M$, say) then picking $x_0>M$ will lead to $B=\emptyset$. If $A^ c$ is not bounded from above, there will always be some $x\in A^c$ with $x>x_0$ and so $B$ will be non-empty.
Note that $\inf \emptyset=+\infty$ by convention, so the claims 1., 2., 3., 4. will still hold:

1: $x_0$ is an obvious lower bound as $B\subseteq [x_0,\infty)$

3: If $B=\emptyset$ then trivially $+\infty>x_0$. If $B\ne\emptyset$, note that the infimum of a bounded from below non-empty closed set belongs to the set, hence $\inf B\in B\subseteq A^c$ and $\notin A$.

2: From 1. and 3. and $x_0\in A$.

4: Any point  $x\in [x_0,\inf B)$ is in $\notin B$, hence $x\notin A^c$ (as clearly $x\in [x_0,\infty)$), i.e. $x\in A$.

For the last part, let $B'=(-\infty,x_0]\cap A^c$ and $\beta=\sup B'$. You get results analoguous to 1., 2., 3., 4. and hence $(\beta,\inf B)=(\sup B',x_0]\cup [x_0,\inf B)\subseteq A$. Note that it may happen that $\beta=-\infty$, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

set $B$ is the intersection of two closed sets: $[x_{0},\infty)$
and $A^{c}$ so it is closed. However if $[x_{0},\infty)\subset A$
then $B=\emptyset$ so it cannot be shown that $B$ is non-empty.
Let us say that $[x_{0},\infty)\subset A$ is not true. Then some
$y$ exists with $y\geq x_{0}$ and $y\in A^{c}$. Then $y\in B$
so $B$ is not empty. In that case we have:

1. for every $x\in B$ it is true that $x\geq x_{0}$.
2. some $\varepsilon>0$ exists such that $\left(x_{0}-\varepsilon,x_{0}+\varepsilon\right)\subset A$
   (because $A$ is open and $x_{0}\in A$). This implies that $B\subset[x_{0}+\varepsilon,\infty)$
   so $\text{inf B}\geq x_{0}+\varepsilon>x_{0}$.
3. let us denote $\text{inf B}$ by $b$. If $b\in A$ then $\left(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon\right)\subset A$
   for some $\varepsilon>0$. Then $\left(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon\right)\cap B=\emptyset$
   contradicting that $b=\text{inf B}$.
4. Let $y\in[x_{0},b)$. If $y\notin A$ then $y\in B$. But $y<b$
   so this contradicts that $b=\text{inf B}$.

Comment: sorry but [x0,∞) and Ac are not closed sets. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @user93765 Both are closed, their complements are open

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are saying that [x0,∞) is a closed set? really?